# Python Shell SMTP debugging server error (Django)

Tags: python, django, smtp

I am trying to test sending mail from the python shell with an SMTP server.
I entered the python shell and then...

```
python -m smtpd -n -c DebuggingServer localhost:1025
```

but I receive this error

```
File "<console>", line 1
python -m smtpd -n -c DebuggingServer localhost:1025
              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Any clue how to fix this? Thanks.

Comment: One can find solution here regarding the problem:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14019578/python-django-smtp-debugserver-doesnt-catch-emails

Answer (score 1):

python shell? I think you should use the the "python -m smtpd -m -n -c ..." directly in the cmd of Windows or terminal of someother OS.

if you want to use in the python shell, try os.system or os.popen

Answer (score 0):

The command you enter`python -m smtpd -n -c DebuggingServer localhost:1025` is not a shell command.
The command has to be directly executed from the terminal or the command prompt.
Note: The command might need sudo privilege to start the smtp server.